# why event can't add without identity

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i remove identity from my database but when i want to add events the database he can not insert 
i don't know what the problem despite when i change my database with identity work .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUFM8.jpg)

```
                                         var data = {
                            EventID: $('#hdEventID').val(),
                            EventTitle: $('#txtSubject').val().trim(),
                            StartDate: $('#txtStart').val().trim(),
                            EndDate: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') ? null : $('#txtEnd').val().trim(),
                            EventDescription: $('#txtDescription').val(),
                            ThemeColor: $('#ddThemeColor').val(),
                            IsFullDay: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked')
                        }
                        SaveEvent(data);
                        // call function for submit data to the server
                    })

                    function SaveEvent(data) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '/home/SaveEvent',
                            data: data,
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.status) {
                                    //Refresh the calender
                                    FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                                    $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                                }
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert('Failed');
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
```

this is my controller in asp mvc :

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveEvent(Event e)
    {
        var status = false;
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        { 
            if (e.EventID > 0)
            {
                //Update the event
                var v = db.Events.Where(a => a.EventID == e.EventID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    v.EventTitle = e.EventTitle;
                    v.StartDate = e.StartDate;
                    v.EndDate = e.EndDate;
                    v.EventDescription = e.EventDescription;
                    v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;

                }
            }

            else
            {
                db.Events.Add(e);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            status = true;
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
    }
```

help me to make the events add without identity :

Answer (score 0):

If autoincrement identity is off you must manually set your EventID since its your primary key.
Read max id from database and set your event id to max+1 before adding it to database.